# Reflect.getMetadata return undefined only in IE11

Tags: typescript

I am learning [Decorators](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)  and found  issue running in IE11, but no problem in chrome and Edge....

only in IE11, Relect.getMetadata() will return undefined.... but in Chrome and edge.. there is no problem..   I only post related part here

```
function validate<T>(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) {
    let set = descriptor.set;
    descriptor.set = function (value: T) {
        let type = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, propertyKey);   // return undefined.
```

I use es5....

Comment: Does it work if you use [Polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/)?